# The binormal to the locus is inclined to the binormal of the given curve at an angle $\tan^{-1}(\frac{c\tau^2}{k\sqrt{c^2\tau^2+1}})$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

> On the binormal of a space curve of constant torsion $\tau$, a point $Q$ is taken at a constant distance $c$ from the curve. Show that the binormal to the locus of $Q$ is inclined to the binormal of the given curve at an angle $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{c\tau^2}{k\sqrt{c^2\tau^2+1}}\right)$

Suppose that a point $Q$ is taken on the binormal of the curve at a constant distance $c$ from the curve. Let, $y(s_1)=\vec{OQ}$ represents the locus of $Q$ on the binormal of $c$. $\vec{OQ}=\vec{OP}+\vec{PQ}$ or $\underline{y}=\underline{x}+c\underline{b}$. Differentiate with respect to $s$,

[image]

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d\underline{y}}{ds_1}\frac{ds_1}{ds}&=\underline{x'}+c\underline{b'}\\
t_1\frac{ds_1}{ds}&=t-c\tau n\\
\left(\frac{ds_1}{ds}\right)^2&=1+c^2\tau^2\\
\frac{ds_1}{ds}&=\sqrt{1+c^2\tau^2}
\end{align}
$$

From here, I couldn't manage to think further. Any help would be appreciated.

I didn't understand how to approach this kind of problem. If anyone has any book suggestion, then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've worked in differential geometry for about 50 years but do not know what the *binomial* of a space curve is. Can you please edit your post to include the relevant definition(s)? "binomial of $c$" doesn't sound meaningful, here.

Comment: Adding in a photo of your handwriting is not helpful. What is there was already typed nicely.

Comment: I mistyped the "binormal" as "binomial" @TedShifrin

Comment: Oh ... This is a locus of points on the binormal lines of the curve. Much better.

Comment: Why is this even an interesting question? It seems like drudgery to me. You can find the Frenet frame of the new curve and dot the binormal vectors, but I don't see that their answer is correct.

Comment: I tried several approaches but failed to reach the answer. I got frustration as I couldn't manage to do things by my own. Are there any good resources on them? @TedShifrin

Comment: There are lots of classic books that cover differential geometry of curves, but this seems a crazy question and the answer seems very wrong to me. Where did you get the question?

Comment: If you look at my differential geometry text (freely available at the link in my profile), you'll find a lot of exercises that use the Frenet frame. I find them more interesting than this one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your book. IDK why my lecturer using a book where no concept was written clearly, only too many exercises added. If you can help me/give any direction with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4549419/736159) then please let me know. Thanks again. @TedShifrin