# Easy way to get the gauss equations in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

> Derive [Gauss formula](https://liavas.net/courses/math430/files/Surfaces_part3.pdf) $$x_{ij}=\Gamma^k_{ij}x_k+L_{ij}\textbf{n}\quad\textrm{(in Einstein notation)}$$
> The coefficients $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ where $i, j, k = 1, 2$ are called Christoffel symbols and the coefficients $L_{ij},i,j = 1, 2$ are called the coefficients of the second fundamental form.

I know one way to get those equations like, letting $x_u,x_v$ and $\textbf{n}$ are linearly independent and may write

$$
\begin{align}
x_{uu}&=a_1x_u+a_2x_v+a_3\textbf{n}\\
x_{uv}&=b_1x_u+b_2x_v+b_3\textbf{n}\\
x_{vv}&=c_1x_u+c_2x_v+c_3\textbf{n}
\end{align}
$$
But the problem is, in this way to get the coefficients are very tedious and computational heavy. Is there any other way to get those equations with less work?

Thanks in advance.

### Update

proof : The three vectors $\mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{u}}, \mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{v}}$ and $\mathrm{N}$ are linearly jependent. so they span the three dimensional vector space.
$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{uu}&=a_1x_u+a_2x_v+a_3\textbf{N}\\
x_{uv}&=b_1x_u+b_2x_v+b_3\textbf{N}\\
x_{vv}&=c_1x_u+c_2x_v+c_3\textbf{N}\\
&\therefore x_{uu} \cdot N=a_3 \Rightarrow e=a_3 \cdots \cdots(4) \\
&x_{uv} \cdot N=b_3 \Rightarrow f=b_3 \cdots \cdots(5) \\
&x_{vv} \cdot N=c_3 \Rightarrow g=c_3 \cdots \cdots(6)
\end{aligned}
$$
We know $E=x_u \cdot x_u, \quad F=x_u \cdot x_v, \quad G=x_v \cdot x_v$
$$
\mathrm{e}=\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{uu}} \cdot \mathbf{N}, f=\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{uv}} \cdot \mathbf{N}, \mathrm{g}=\mathrm{x}_{\mathrm{vv}} \cdot \mathbf{N}
$$
Differentiating $E=x_u \cdot x_u$ w.r.t. $u$, we have,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& E_{u}=x_{uu} \cdot x_{u}+x_{u} \cdot x_{uu}=2 x_{uu} \cdot x_u \\
\Rightarrow & x_{uu} \cdot x_{u}=\frac{1}{2} E_u \cdots \cdots(7)
\end{aligned}
$$
Again, differentiating $\mathrm{E}=x_{u} \cdot x_u$ w.r.t. v, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
& E_v=x_{uv} \cdot x_{u}+x_{u} \cdot x_{uv}=2 x_{uv} \cdot x_{u} \\
\Rightarrow & x_{uv} \cdot x_{u}=\frac{1}{2} E_v \cdots \cdots(8)
\end{aligned}
$$
Also, differentiating $\mathrm{G}=\mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{v}} \cdot \mathbf{x}_v$ w.r.t. $u$ and $\mathrm{v}$, we respectively
$$
\begin{aligned}
& G_u=x_{uv} \cdot x_v+x_v \cdot x_{uv} \text { and } G_v=x_{vv} \cdot x_v+x_v \cdot x_{vv} \\
\Rightarrow & G_u=2 x_{uv} \cdot x_v \\
\Rightarrow & x_{uv} \cdot x_v=\frac{1}{2} G_u \cdots \cdots \cdot(9) \quad \Rightarrow x_{vv} \cdot x_v=\frac{1}{2} G_v \cdots \ldots \cdot(10)
\end{aligned}
$$

### Update 2

So, there's no way to avoid this type of calculation without introducing some advance stuff. I read the proof once again and notice I couldn't manage to get ideas for the following lines:

$x_{u u}=\frac{G E_u-2 F F_u+F E_v}{2\left(E G-F^2\right)} x_u+\frac{2 E F_u-E E_v-F E_u}{2\left(E G-F^2\right)} x_v+e N$

$x_{u v}=\frac{G E_v-F G_u}{2\left(E G-F^2\right)} x_u+\frac{E_u-F E_v}{2\left(E G-F^2\right)} x_v+f N$

$\mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{vv}}=\frac{2 \mathrm{GF}_{\mathrm{v}}-\mathrm{GG}_u-\mathrm{FG}_{\mathrm{v}}}{2\left(\mathrm{EG}-\mathrm{F}^2\right)} \mathbf{x}_{\mathrm{u}}+\frac{\mathrm{EG}_{\mathrm{v}}-2 \mathrm{FF}_{\mathrm{v}}+\mathrm{FG}_{u}}{2\left(E G-\mathrm{F}^2\right)}+\mathrm{g} N$

These equations can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
&x_{u u}=\Gamma_{11}^1 x_{11}+\Gamma_{11}^2 x_v+e N \\
&x_{u v}=\Gamma_{12}^1 x_{11}+\Gamma_{12}^2 x_v+f N \\
&x_{v v}=\Gamma_{22}^1 x_{11}+\Gamma_{22}^2 x_v+g N
\end{aligned}
$$

I didn't understand how they replace those coefficients with chistoffel symbols.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking? Particularly: 1. It sounds as if you know a proof, but it's "too tedious/computationally heavy" for some purpose. What actual constraints are there, so people here don't construct an unacceptable calculation? 2. We could _define_ the Christoffel symbols and second fundamental form components to be the coefficients making the stated system work. Is there a working definition implicit in the question that prevents doing that? 3. Do you know about differential forms and moving (co-)frames?

Comment: We haven't introduced differential forms and moving (co-)frames yet @AndrewD.Hwang I will update the post to add some context of that proof.

Comment: There are two more pages. Sorry, I couldn't type them all for now. If I need to add them, please let me know. @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: To me these equations define the Christoffel symbols (and the second fundamental form is already defined, consistent with this). One can then derive formulas for the Christoffel symbols from the first fundamental form as you are doing. There is no way to avoid computations, and they will get worse. See Section  3 of Chapter 2 of my differential geometry text.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. As Ted says, there's not a way to avoid this type of calculation, though moving frames can help organize (at the cost of expressing the issue using matrix-valued differential forms).

Comment: I see. I read the proof once again and notice I couldn't manage to get ideas/intuition for some lines added in the update 2. Can you help me with that then? @TedShifrin Thanks again.

Comment: I suggest you read the exposition in my text.

Comment: I read several sections, specially from chapter 1 and 2. But I see in chapter 2-section 3,  **We have to this point considered only the normal components of the second derivatives $\mathbf{x}_{u u}, \mathbf{x}_{u v}$, and $\mathbf{x}_{v v}$. Now let's consider them in toto. Since $\left\{\mathbf{x}_u, \mathbf{x}_v, \mathbf{n}\right\}$ gives a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, there are functions $\Gamma_{u u}^u, \Gamma_{u u}^v, \Gamma_{u v}^u=\Gamma_{v u}^u, \Gamma_{u v}^v=\Gamma_{v u}^v$, $\Gamma_{v v}^u$, and $\Gamma_{v v}^v$ so that** (1/n)

Comment: $$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbf{x}_{u u}=\Gamma_{u u}^u \mathbf{x}_u+\Gamma_{u u}^v \mathbf{x}_v+\ell \mathbf{n} \\
&\mathbf{x}_{u v}=\Gamma_{u v}^u \mathbf{x}_u+\Gamma_{u v}^v \mathbf{x}_v+m \mathbf{n} \\
&\mathbf{x}_{v v}=\Gamma_{v v}^u \mathbf{x}_u+\Gamma_{v v}^v \mathbf{x}_v+n \mathbf{n} .
\end{aligned}
$$I still didn't get the intuition to directly write them using these symbols. And what is the meaning of **toto**? @TedShifrin (2/n)

Comment: *In toto* is a phrase from Latin, meaning altogether. We are *defining* the Christoffel symbols to be the coefficients of the tangential parts of the second derivatives. As with curve theory, we want to see geometry of the surface in terms of the basis $x_u, x_v, n$.

Comment: **We are defining the Christoffel symbols to be the coefficients of the tangential parts of the second derivatives**, so suppose I don't know they work, then what make me to think to define it like this way. Actually, what make me worried is, in tensor calculus I know the christoffel symbol mean how much of the change in the basis vector with respect to the coordinate in the direction of specific vector.

Comment: I can't interpret this intuition with these equations naturally. That's why bothering you too much. I hope you don't mind. @TedShifrin

Comment: Forget tensor calculus until you’ve mastered this. But you said (sloppily) the exact same definition.

Comment: I didn't understand how $\frac{G E_u-2 F F_u+F E_v}{2\left(E G-F^2\right)}=\Gamma_{11}^1$ these two are equal? @TedShifrin, Is the OP mistyped it? Can you redirect me any complete proof of this? TIA

Comment: Did you look at the derivation(s) in my text? This is there explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are talking about [this](https://imgur.com/VSBpmp0.png). Thank you for your response. @TedShifrin